# Two way binding in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I get a problem with follwoing code.

my html page code :

```
<body ng-app="myapp">

    <div ng-controller="myController">
    The message is {{message}}
        <input type="button" value="Change Message" ng-click="changeMessage()">

   </div>
```

My Controller code:

```
app.controller('myController',function($scope)
{              
 $scope.changeMessage=function()
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Message changed");
      $scope.message="Hurray !!! New Message";    

        },3000);

$scope.newMessage=function()
        {
            $scope.message="hello";
            console.log("new message");
        };
```

But if I use changeMessage function I am not able to see the changed Message property even though the console.log message comes.
what is missing here in both cases.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the change isn't reflected in the view is that because of the assignment is done in the callback in `setTimeout` which results in angular not noticing the change. This has to do with the so called `digest` cycle. There are different ways to solve this.

use `$scope.$apply()` to wrap your assignment

or even better use the existing `$timeout` service provided by angular instead of the call to `setTimeout` which already handles the problem above for you.

For details, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout for usage of $timeout

and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope for the reasons behind $apply.

A general explanation of what is happening here is described at http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 0):

you should use $digest() after that the timeout is done:

```
$scope.changeMessage=function()
{
   setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.message="Hurray !!! New Message";  
    $scope.$digest();
   },3000);
}
```

please note that it is much better to use $digest instead of $apply (performance related):

scope.$digest() will fire watchers on the current scope, and on all of its children, too. scope.$apply will evaluate passed function and run $rootScope.$digest()

Answer (score 0):

every change should happen within an angular-digest-cycle. if you change values from the outside (which is exactly what happens, if you use `setTimeout` instead of angular's `$timeout`) angular does not update your view until the next digest-cycle (https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/). so in your case the `message` is already set, but the view has not been updated.

try something like this:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.changeMessage = function() {
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log("Message changed");
      $scope.message="Hurray !!! New Message";    
    }, 3000);

  $scope.newMessage=function() {
    $scope.message="hello";
    console.log("new message");
  };
```